# Getting Authentication error logging in to communtity through hybrid remote app

Tags: community, mobile, sfdcmobilesdk-android, hybrid, hybrid-remote

i have created the hybrid remote application, when i login it gives a toast message saying 'error: Authentication error, please try again'.

I am using android emulator to test it.
Forcehybrid version 7.3.0

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, i have done below changes.

In connected app i added this scope

Access and manage your data (api)
Full access (full)
Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
Provide access to custom applications (visualforce)
Provide access to your data via the Web (web)

In profile i gave access to the community.

Comment: You do not need (and should not give) "Full Access".  You only need api, refresh/token access, and web.